# Using SpeechKit for iOS using Swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, speech-recognition

I've used Nuance SpeechKit for some months using Objective-C. Now I'm coding in Swift - except for the class where I instantiate the SKRecognizer and SpeechKit has stopped working.

When I try to initialise the SKRecognizer object I get the following error:`NMSP_ERROR] check status Error: 696e6974 init -> line: 485 makeFullPathname`

Is it possible that it's because I'm using swift in the rest of the project?

Comment: My project is in the same context as yours, regarding swift usage, I have the same error, but still, everything works fine with Nuance. 
Check if the "not working" part is really coming from that error or not.

Comment: Hi @tf.alves Have you made a complete Speechkit implementation in Swift? If so, I am wondering how to initialize the SpeechKit.setupWithID () object (the delegate parameter is surely wrong...) I can open a question so you can answer it, and give you the Green Tick, what do you say??

Comment: @Josh ok, do that and link me to the question :) 
Just a small note: I've implemented speechkit for the voice recognition part, not for voice synthesizer, as we have a native API for that now. But its easy after you setup SpeechKit, just follow the instructions to get it going :)

Comment: @tf.alves The speech recon is fair enough! I am having trouble with the delegate parameter while initializing. My speech recon is only half way working, it starts, but the methods that listen to onStart, onFinish, onResult  are not triggering, I can tell because on the log I see activity from the [NMSP] debugger showing some audio related info. I have posted the question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30327372/how-to-delegate-listener-functions-from-objectivec-class-to-a-swift-view-control/30329129?noredirect=1#comment48756821_30329129

Comment: The implementation in Swift is different, check out the answer posted for a question that I already asked about this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30327372/implementing-nuance-speech-recognition-on-swift-cannot-listen-to-onresult-oner