# 9Implementing Nuance Speech Recognition on Swift, cannot listen to onResult, onError... events

Tags: ios, swift, delegates, speech-recognition, header-files

I have two parts of my Speech Recon project with Nuance, the .h file of a module (ObjectiveC) and a`ViewController` (swift).

I want to set up a`SpeechRecognition` object in my swift`viewController`, and listen to onBegin, onStop... and such methods.

The only way to make it compile is to use nil as the delegate parameter to initialize the SpeechRecon object. Obviously this is not good because my onStart... and onFinish functions don´t trigger.

I have implemented a protocol to the`SKRecogniser` file, and extended my ViewController class to SKReconDelegate... but if I use "self" as a delegate to initialize object, the compiler will say that`UIViewController` is not a valid class. I know I need to establish some delegate between both classes, but I am an android developers, and my iOS skills are still not sharp enough.
Here is the code, if I missed some important piece just let me know.
I will be very thankful for your help.

```
//ViewController code, in SWIFT
//NO PROTOCOLS NEEDED HERE!

class ViewController:  UIViewController, SpeechKitDelegate, SKRecognizerDelegate{

override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        SpeechKit.setupWithID( "NMDPTRIAL_nuance_chch_com9999",
            host:"sandbox.nmdp.nuancemility.net",
            port:443,
            useSSL:false,
            delegate:self) //error said "self" is of an invalid ViewController type :( because I was NOT implementing all 4 methods BELOW:
   }
//a bit ahead, I have the same problem with a button
@IBAction func btnmicaction(sender: AnyObject) {
   self.voiceSearch=SKRecognizer(type: "websearch", detection: 2, language: langType as String, delegate: self) //error said "self" is of an invalid ViewController type :( because I was NOT implementing all 4 methods BELOW:
   }


//IMPLEMENT ALL THESE 4 FUNCTIONS, AS SUGGESTED BY THE SOLUTION
func recognizerDidBeginRecording(recognizer:SKRecognizer){
        println("************** ReconBeganRecording")
        }

func recognizerDidFinishRecording(recognizer:SKRecognizer){
        println("************** ReconFinishedRecording")
        }

func recognizer(recognizer: SKRecognizer!, didFinishWithResults results: SKRecognition!){
    //The voice recognition process has understood something
    }

func recognizer(recognizer: SKRecognizer!, didFinishWithError error: NSError!, suggestion: String!){
   //an error has occurred
   }
}
```

Just in case, here is my Bridge header:

```
#ifndef Vanilla_Bridge_h
#define Vanilla_Bridge_h
#import <SpeechKit/SpeechKit.h>
```

**UPDATE**
SEE SOLUTION BELOW!!

Comment: Why are you defining `SKRecognizerDelegate` in your `ViewController`? You should be using definition from `SpeechKit`

Comment: @JakubVano My goal is to satisfy the delegate parameter of the: "SpeechKit.setupWithID" function, and make the listener functions trigger, but my knowledge about delegates is exhausted and I cant figure out what to put there.

Comment: I mean, protocol is defined in the `SKRecognizer.h`. If you re-define it in your Swift code, name `SKRecognizerDelegate` will mean different protocol than `SKRecognizer` is expecting. Try removing `SKRecognizerDelegate` definition from your Swift file.

Comment: @Josh, yes, you definitely should not redeclare `SKRecognizerDelegate`. I am surprised this even compiled. Definitely remove the Swift definition and update us with any new issues.

Comment: @Firo I removed the protocol (in the question above, too) And I am getting this error: "Cannot find an initializer for type 'SKRecognizer' that accepts an argument list of type '(type: String, detection: Int, language: String, delegate: ViewController)" and this error in the class declaration: "/Users/JoshArtificialSolutions/Documents/Vanilla/Vanilla/ViewController.swift:1‌​5:1: Type 'ViewController' does not conform to protocol 'SKRecognizerDelegate'"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's what I've got
Bridging Header:

```
#import <SpeechKit/SpeechKit.h>
#import "NuanceHeader.h"
```

NuanceHeader.h:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
@interface NuanceHeader : NSObject
@end
```

NuanceHeader.m

```
#import "NuanceHeader.h"
const unsigned char SpeechKitApplicationKey[] = {...};
@implementation NuanceHeader
@end
```

When it comes to the UIViewController that uses all this:

```
class MyViewController: UIViewController, SpeechKitDelegate, SKRecognizerDelegate
{
    var voiceSearch: SKRecognizer?

    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
       //Setup SpeechKit
       SpeechKit.setupWithID("...", host: "sandbox.nmdp.nuancemobility.net", port: 443, useSSL: false, delegate: self)
    }

    func someAction()
    {
        self.voiceSearch = SKRecognizer(type: SKSearchRecognizerType, detection: UInt(SKLongEndOfSpeechDetection), language:"eng-USA", delegate: self)

    }

    func recognizerDidBeginRecording(recognizer: SKRecognizer!)
    {
        //The recording has started
    }

    func recognizerDidFinishRecording(recognizer: SKRecognizer!)
    {
        //The recording has stopped
    }

    func recognizer(recognizer: SKRecognizer!, didFinishWithResults results: SKRecognition!)
    {
        //The voice recognition process has understood something
    }

    func recognizer(recognizer: SKRecognizer!, didFinishWithError error: NSError!, suggestion: String!)
    {
       //an error has occurred
    }
}
```

There is nothing else to it, check every step, this part is pretty straight forward

Comment: Man it works!!! I would give you 10 green ticks if I could! I had many more SpeechKit/blabla imports in the header file interfering, also, I was not implementing 2 of the 4 methods you mentioned, so using "self" as a delegate would not work.

Comment: That was probably it, not having the required methods by the protocol makes the UIViewController non-conformant to that protocol, the message can be a bit tricky though, because it seems as everything is OK, when actually is not. I'm glad it helped ;)

Comment: Hi @Josh I'm having the same issue. Where do I need to add NuanceHeader.h and NuanceHeader.m

Comment: I've implemented all four required methods.

Comment: @Vakas If you are also working with Swift, just put this on your Bridge.h file: #import <SpeechKit/SpeechKit.h>  Also, dont forget to put the delegates on the class definitions, and to override its 4 functions, like I did in the Question I asked above. Dont forget to upload if it works, pls. Luck!

Comment: Thanks, also I needed to add the following import to the ViewController: UIKit, AudioToolbox, AVFoundation, SystemConfiguration.

Comment: @Josh I added everything above but get "undeclared type" error https://www.evernote.com/l/AA5m25StYhhIJ6osUeM2fuRUADeaPgwaSZ4 any ideas?

Comment: I went ahead and posted a new question with more details on my specific situation: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35817358/speechkit-pod-for-swift-results-in-undeclared-type-errors

Comment: Hi @Sean , I will reply in the new question that you opened.

Comment: Hi alves do you have objectice c code to implement nuance framework.

Comment: Hi Arun, unfortunately I don't have it in objective-c as it is not my forte. Sorry

Answer (score 0):

Try `let objCDelegate = self as SKRecognizerDelegate` and then use `objCDelegate` as delegate parameter

Comment: It compiles, but crashes at runtime: "Could not cast value of type 'Vanilla.ViewController' (0x10c7b4640) to 'SKRecognizerDelegate'"

Comment: Really? What is your Xcode's version. Mine is 6.3.2 and it doesn't crash.

Comment: Mine is also 6.3.2, the delegate seems to be of the correct type, but somehow it is not being accepted because: "SKRecognizerDelegate has no accessible initializers".   In the .h file, the init function is: "(id)initWithType:(NSString *)type detection:(SKEndOfSpeechDetection)detection language:(NSString *)language delegate:(id <SKRecognizerDelegate>)delegate;" that "ID" with those "< >" symbols don´t convince me....

Comment: It's weird. The `id` with `<>` doesn't matter. Try clean or quit your Xcode and build again. If it still doesn't work, you should directly ask Nuance.

Answer (score 0):

Since things have changed a bit I thought I would add my 2 cents:

```
 var listening = false
var transaction: SKTransaction?
var session: SKSession?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    session = SKSession(URL: NSURL(string: serverURL), appToken: appKey)

    let audioFormat = SKPCMFormat()
    audioFormat.sampleFormat = .SignedLinear16;
    audioFormat.sampleRate = 16000;
    audioFormat.channels = 1;

    print("\(NSHomeDirectory())/start.mp3")

    // Attach them to the session
    session!.startEarcon = SKAudioFile(URL: NSURL(fileURLWithPath: "\(NSHomeDirectory())/start.mp3"), pcmFormat: audioFormat)
    session!.endEarcon = SKAudioFile(URL: NSURL(fileURLWithPath: "\(NSHomeDirectory())/stop.mp3"), pcmFormat: audioFormat)

}

@IBAction func speechButtonDidClick(sender: AnyObject) {

    if listening == false {
        transaction = session?.recognizeWithType(SKTransactionSpeechTypeDictation,
                                                    detection: .Short,
                                                    language: "eng-USA",
                                                    delegate: self)

    }else{
        transaction?.stopRecording()
    }
}

// SKTransactionDelegate
func transactionDidBeginRecording(transaction: SKTransaction!) {
    messageText.text = "listening"
    listening = true
    indicator.startAnimating()
    startPollingVolume()
}
func transactionDidFinishRecording(transaction: SKTransaction!) {
    messageText.text = "stopped"
    listening = false
    indicator.stopAnimating()
    stopPollingVolume()
}

func transaction(transaction: SKTransaction!, didReceiveRecognition recognition: SKRecognition!) {

    print("got something")

    //Take the best result
    if recognition.text != nil{
        speechTextField.text = recognition.text
    }
}
func transaction(transaction: SKTransaction!, didReceiveServiceResponse response: [NSObject : AnyObject]!) {
    print ("service response")
    print(response)
}
func transaction(transaction: SKTransaction!, didFinishWithSuggestion suggestion: String!) {
}
func transaction(transaction: SKTransaction!, didFailWithError error: NSError!, suggestion: String!) {
    print ("error")
    print(error)
}


var timer = NSTimer()
var interval = 0.01;

func startPollingVolume() {
    timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(interval,
                                                   target: self,
                                                   selector: #selector(ViewController.pollVolume),
                                                   userInfo: nil,
                                                   repeats: true)
}

func pollVolume() {
    if transaction != nil{
        let volumeLevel:Float = transaction!.audioLevel
        audioLevelIndicator.progress = volumeLevel / 90
    }
}

func stopPollingVolume() {
    timer.invalidate()
    audioLevelIndicator.progress = 0
}
```

hope this helps someone!