# Is there any way to load const unsigned char from plist in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, plist

I have some data for my app authorisation like {0x7c, 0x1e, ...} and I need to get it in Objective-C file like:

```
const unsigned char ApplicationKey[] = {0x7c, 0x1e, ...};
```

Is there any way to get this const from plist-file?

I need this because according to this answer [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30327372/implementing-nuance-speech-recognition-on-swift-cannot-listen-to-onresult-oner) this is the thing in NuanceHeader.m And I would like just store my AppKey in plist, neither in code.

Comment: The question makes no sense. How did this get into a plist file in the first place?

Comment: ...you add it to a plist file?
What doesn't make sense?

Comment: Why do you want to set **ApplicationKey** with the [const keyword](http://duramecho.com/ComputerInformation/WhyHowCppConst.html)?  What are you trying to prevent? Compile time error checking? Or are you trying to make your application temper-proof on jailbreak systems?

Answer (score 0):

Fundamentally a plist can contain numeric values in the form of `NSNumber` instances.  You can create an `unsigned char` from those fairly easily:

```
NSString* pathToPlist = // Determine path to plist
NSArray* plist = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:pathToPlist];
unsigned char applicationKey[plist.count];
[plist enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(NSNumber* number, NSUInteger index, BOOL* stop) {
    applicationKey[index] = [number unsignedCharValue];
}];
```

Comment: Why would you do this? Why not put actual `NSData` in the plist?

Comment: @rmaddy, would that question not be better asked to the questioner?  He's the one who specified a plist.

Comment: @Avi No, it's a question for Charles. The OP is asking about binary data in a plist but this answer is about an array of numbers in a plist.

Comment: I guess you can read it either way.  Since we don't know how the plist is created (if it even has been), we don't know what's in it.

Comment: Added the reason to the question.

Comment: @rmaddy I read the question as asking about storing an array of unsigned char values in a plist, hence my answer.  If he's using nuance though, I think he just needs a String anyway.  As such, neither char values as numbers or binary data is probably the appropriate way to go when you can just throw a String in a plist directly.