# SpeechKit Pod for Swift results in undeclared type errors

Tags: ios, swift, compiler-errors, cocoapods, speechkit

I have implemented the Nuance SpeechKit using this [CocoaPod](https://cocoapods.org/pods/SpeechKit) https://cocoapods.org/pods/SpeechKit and implementing the instructions from the [accepted S.O. answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30327372/implementing-nuance-speech-recognition-on-swift-cannot-listen-to-onresult-oner?answertab=votes#tab-top) here: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30327372/implementing-nuance-speech-recognition-on-swift-cannot-listen-to-onresult-oner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30327372/implementing-nuance-speech-recognition-on-swift-cannot-listen-to-onresult-oner?answertab=votes#tab-top)

After doing so I get a "use of undeclared type 'SKRecognizerDelegate'" error:

**Supporting Files:**
[image]
[image]
and
[image]

**Errors in UIViewController:**
[image: SKRecognizerDelegate error screen]

Answer (score 0):

The only difference I see are these #ifndef / #define lines in your bridge file,

```
#ifndef Vanilla_Bridge_h
#define Vanilla_Bridge_h
#import <SpeechKit/SpeechKit.h>
```

In any case I think it is a bridge file error, try to remove it and add it again with this guide: http://www.learnswiftonline.com/getting-started/adding-swift-bridging-header/ Good luck!

Comment: I don't see the "Vanilla_Bridge_h" line in my files or in the files of the website you listed (http://www.learnswiftonline.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/swift_bridging_header_3.png). Are you saying I need to add them?

Comment: Vanilla is the project name, in my case. Those lines were there when the bridge file was autogenerated, so I guess they are required. @Sean